# How to check if these vectors are normal or orthogonal?

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

If we have number of vectors.
$a = (1, 0, 2, 0)$
$b = (-2, 1, 0, -1)$
$c = (-1, 1, 2, -1)$

How to check if they are normal, or orthogonal vectors?

Comment: How have you defined the word "orthogonal"?

Comment: Orthogonal (perpendicular) to each other

Comment: Do you know how to compute the angle between two vectors?

Comment: Do you know what the dot product is?

Comment: ya I know. for both

Comment: So what is the angle between two orthogonal vectors?

Comment: it should be  90

Comment: Use the formula for the angle between two vectors and see if it is $90^\circ$ for any pair of your vectors.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how to know if they are normal?

Comment: If the angle between two vectors is $90^\circ$ then they will be normal. Can you see what the dot product of two vectors must equal to if the angle between them is $90^\circ$, that is, if they are normal?

Comment: if a.b = 0, then they are normal.

Comment: Correct. So then you must see if any two of the vectors have a dot product of 0. For non-zero vectors, their dot product will be 0 if and only if they are normal (perpendicular) to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dot Product and Orthogonal Vectors:**

Vectors **$\vec {a}$** and **$\vec{b}$** are orthogonal (or perpendicular) to each other if, $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0$.

**Further Notes:**

([Dot Product](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/DotProduct.aspx))